# How can I display the images from database to GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview

Hello I try to display image from database to GridView but I store only part of the image path (Uploade/imageName.png)
how to put the hole path in GridView (~/image/Uploade/imageName.png) to display the image.

mycode :

```
                        <AlternatingRowStyle Width="100px" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="select">
                                <ControlStyle ForeColor="Orange"></ControlStyle>
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="path" 
                                ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="100">
                                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
                            </asp:ImageField>

                        </Columns>

                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the picture, and just drop into the grid a plane jane image control.

You can then use a Eval() expression for data binding like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PicName" HeaderText="Picture Name"/>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
                        ImageUrl='<%# "~/Image/" + Eval("PicPath")  %>' 
                        Height="200px" Width="200px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

So, you do have to put that control "in side" of a ItemTemplate.

So, my code to load the grid would thus be this:

So, my data table is thus this:

[image]

But, as noted, the path name does not include the first part (Image/).

And our code to load, could be this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, PicName, PicPath FROM tblPictures",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

So you are quite much free to have/use an expression for the picture path - including that of adding the extra folder you need/want in that path name.